# wxStyledTextCtrl Unicode clipboard copy/paste problem in Linux

Tags: wxwidgets, clipboard

My app uses the wxStyledTextCtrl (STC) and I'm running into a problem when copy/pasting unicode characters out of the STC. I'm able to paste unicode strings into the STC but unable copy out of the STC. The problem exists under Linux but not under macOS.

The problem can be demonstrated using the wxWidgets `stctest` sample app.

Experiment:

- Launch `stctest` and paste some unicode string (e.g. αβγδεζηθικλμ)
  into it. It will succeed.
- Select any or all the unicode characters in the STC and copy.
- Now try to paste it into any other suitable app like your code editor, a word processor, or even another running instance of
  `stctest`. Under Linux it will fail. However, if you paste it
  somewhere else in the same STC, it will succeed.

I have looked at the library file src/gtk/clipbrd.cpp but I’m not very familiar with the GTK API and it is not obvious to me what’s wrong.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 with Wayland and wxWidgets 3.2.2.1.
I built the wxWidgets library using
`../configure --disable-shared --enable-cxx11 --prefix="$(pwd)" --with-gtk=3 --with-libpng=builtin`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: since you can reproduce it in the sample I suggest to open an issue at github.com/wxWidgets/wxwidgets and someone will look into it. I also presume that you tried to run the pure Scintilla code and it also failed.

Comment: you should also try to build the debug version of the wxWidgets by passing `--enable-debug` to configure, completely rebuilding the library  and see what is happening in the `STC` paste event.

Comment: @Igor: I rebuilt the wxWidgets library and `stctest` for debug as you suggested and I got the message *../src/gtk/clipbrd.cpp(756): assert ""m_formatSupported"" failed in GetData(): error retrieving data from clipboard* when I try to paste on the second `stctest` instance. More importantly, when I switched from Wayland to X11 the problem went away. Clearly the problem relates with Wayland. I also opened an issued in GitHub.

Comment: I saw it. You should have mentioned that it's only happening on Wayland.  But let's wait and see - hopefully someone will chime in.

Comment: There are several Unicode formats. Which format are you reading back? For example, Windows natively uses Wide Chars, macOS uses UTF-8, and Linux depends on compile time options.

Comment: @John Hanley, I don't know exactly how to answer your question. I built the library as shown in the original post and at the time of failure I don't get any data back. In my test program I call `wxTheClipboard->GetData(data)` and the data object has no text in it.
When I call `wxTheClipboard->IsSupported()` passing either `wxDF_TEXT` or `wxDF_UNICODETEXT` the return value is true.

Comment: You will need to look at the generated makefile that includes the compiler options and flags. Your post does not show `wxTheClipboard` usage. This [guide](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_unicode.html) might be useful.

Comment: Igor and John Hanley, thank much for your help. The diligent development team at github.com/wxWidgets/wxwidgets is addressing the issue.